# Is it possible to add a RadioButtonList to items in a CheckBoxList?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I've not been able to find a solution (or a definitive answer if it's possible) to do this:

I'm building a checkboxlist in vb.net to display on an asp.net page.  That's working fine, it looks something like this:

[image: Sample]

the aspx for the checkboxlist is this:

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="AppList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" 
        Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Black">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I'd like to be able to list a RadioButtonList between each checkbox, containing the items that currently show inside the parenthesis for each checkboxlist item.

Is this even possible?  And/Or, should I continue to try to solve.

Comment: Use a repeater and add what you want.

Comment: I'll look into using a repeater.  Just haven't used that before, but, I'll give it a shot.  Thanks.